# Ajax request returns 404 from S3 Signed URL

Tags: d3.js, amazon-s3

So, I generated a signed URL in PHP and I want to serve that file to d3js but the ajax request always returns 404.

Sample signed URL format: https://bucket_name_here.s3.amazonaws.com/55rq526afa-efd0-43ba-234b-74ccbb1c4d26.csv?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=DAFAGHDAGGAHHH/20181016/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181016T214022Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=signature_here

D3js

```
d3.csv(signed_url_above, function(error, data){
    ...
});
```

I can download the file via the browser, but not via the Ajax request. I already enabled CORS request with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
  <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
  <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
  <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
  <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
  <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
  <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
  <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Updated: actual error from the request

```
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Is there a message associated with the error?

Comment: @ialarmedalien updated the question

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, did you ever get it working?